# Differences between slice and container/list

Tags: list, go, slice

I'm just getting starting with Go and I have a situation where I need to make a set of entities whose size/length is only known at runtime. I first thought using a list would be a good fit but soon realized slices are the idiomatic data structure in Go.
Curious, I wrote the following benchmarks

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "testing"
)

var N = 10000000

func BenchmarkSlices(B *testing.B) {
    s := make([]int, 1)
    for i := 0; i < N; i += 1 {
        s = append(s, i)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLists(B *testing.B) {
    l := list.New()
    for i := 0; i < N; i += 1 {
        l.PushBack(i)
    }
}
```

which gave me

```
BenchmarkSlices-4       2000000000               0.03 ns/op
BenchmarkLists-4               1        1665489308 ns/op
```

Given that `append` would create a new array and copy all the data over from the old to the new array when the old array gets full, I was expected lists to perform better than slices in the example above. However, my expectations are obviously wrong and I'm trying to understand why.

I wrote the following in order to understand a little better how `append` creates new arrays when it needs to:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func describe(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len = %d, cap = %d\n", len(s), cap(s))
}

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 2)
    for i := 0; i < 15; i += 1 {
        fmt.Println(i)
        describe(s)
        s = append(s, i)
    }
}
```

which gave me

```
0
len = 2, cap = 2
1
len = 3, cap = 4
2
len = 4, cap = 4
3
len = 5, cap = 8
4
len = 6, cap = 8
5
len = 7, cap = 8
6
len = 8, cap = 8
7
len = 9, cap = 16
8
len = 10, cap = 16
9
len = 11, cap = 16
10
len = 12, cap = 16
11
len = 13, cap = 16
12
len = 14, cap = 16
13
len = 15, cap = 16
14
len = 16, cap = 16
```

My only guess at the moment as for why slices perform better than lists is that allocating  memory for a new array whose size is double and copying all the data over is faster than allocating memory for a single element each time an insertion happens.
Is my guess correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: You talk about `append` creating new arrays--`append` only works with slices, not arrays. I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: `container/list` provides doubly-linked lists. If you need a doubly-linked list, use this. If you don't need a doubly-linked list, don't use it. Performance should not enter into consideration.

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you your messages.

As far as I know, there can't be slice without an array under the hood. Therefore, if I understand correctly, `append` will create an array and a slice and return the latter. Is this correct?
I didn't go this deep into the details because I believed it was not a relevant information to the question I'm actually asking.
Thank you for pointing out this detail however, it's true the way I worded it could be misleading to some people.

Comment: @Flimzy That was my stance at first too. However, by going through some code and articles, I got the feeling people tend to use slices if they can solve a problem with it, even when lists would be a better fit. It got me a little confused, which is why I started to wonder if performance was one of the reasons why people tend to go for slices as much as possible.
Do you think I should go with lists if it makes sense in terms of data structure and leave out slices, despite them being (apparently?) idiomatic?

Comment: I use slices instead of doubly linked lists because I almost never need a doubly linked list. Despite the inordinate amount of time discussing linked lists and doubly linked lists during my university days, I've only ever needed a doubly linked list during my programming career maybe once.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the feedback, I appreciate :)

Answer (score 5):

You are running the benchmarks wrong. You should first set up the initial data structure and then run the operation being benchmarked as many times as the `testing.B` instance indicates.

I replaced your code with:

```
var N = 1

func BenchmarkSlices(B *testing.B) {
    s := make([]int, 1)
    for n := 0; n < B.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
            s = append(s, i)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkLists(B *testing.B) {
    l := list.New()
    for n := 0; n < B.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
            l.PushBack(i)
        }
    }
}
```

And got this result:

```
BenchmarkSlices-4       100000000               14.3 ns/op
BenchmarkLists-4         5000000               275 ns/op
```

At least this time the difference seems reasonable and not like a trillion times.

Note that I also replaced the value of `N` to 1 so that `ns/op` actually means `nanoseconds per operation` and not `nanoseconds per N operations`. However, this might also impact the results.

Now onto your question: linked lists, as implemented in Go, suffer from additional costs when compared to simply adding another int to a pre-allocated slice: the list method needs to create a new [Element](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element), wrap your value in an `interface{}` and reassign some pointers.

Meanwhile appending to a slice which has not maxed out its capacity will result in just a few instructions at the CPU level: move an int to a memory location, increment the length of the slice, and you're done.

There is also the fact that the underlying allocator might reallocate the slice in place thus avoiding the need to copy the existing underlying array elements at all.

Comment: Good answer and upvoted, but I think in your benchmarks you shouldn't set `N` to 1. If `N` is larger, it'll force some reallocations in the slice case, which should make the comparison closer. Which is relevant, because the question specifically mentions that being of interest.

Comment: Oh, I misread your code, the benchmark cases blur into each other. I don't think that's sound at all -- why not re-initialize the list/slice each time, and append N (N large) times in each benchmark run?

Comment: You have to be consistent in your benchmark for ns/op to make sense. If you *want* to benchmark the time of "allocation + N appends", then you can absolutely do it. But then your numbers will mean "nanoseconds per allocation + N appends".

Comment: If you want to know how fast someone runs, you don't measure how far they run in 10s, and then see how long they take to run 100 times that and compute their average speed from that. The further they run, the slower they get, so if they happen to run fast in the first 10s then they'll have a longer distance to run and get a slower average speed. This is exactly what your benchmark (and the testing stdlib) is doing here.

Comment: @justinas Thank you very much for your reply and for fixing the benchmark code :)
The need for creating a `Element` is part of what I was referring to in "allocating memory for a single element each time an insertion happens".
Just to confirm: are you saying that creating a `Element` is so heavy that it is slower than creating a new slice and copying all the data over when a slice maxes out? Or maybe it is not deterministic and one should just not worry about it?